# Statement-level trigger in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I can't fully understand how a statement-level trigger works. It executes once for each transaction right? If I have this AFTER INSERT trigger and what it does inside is that it updates one specific column if it meets the condition (ex for column status, `UPDATE table_name SET STATUS = "Single" WHERE COLUMN is null`).

Are the newly inserted data only the ones get to be affected? Or every data in the table that has this null value in column status. I'll be glad hearing your knowledge about this.

Comment: "*It executes once for each transaction*"  - **no**. It executes once for each **statement** - as the name implies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A statement level trigger will fire once after the triggering statement has run, unlike a row level trigger which fires for each affected row.

After statement triggers are generally used to do processing of the set of data - e.g. logging into a table, or running some post-statement processing (usually a procedure).

If you're wanting to update a value in every affected row, then I would advise using a before row level trigger. The update statement in your question would affect all rows where the COLUMN column is null.

Whether a trigger is actually the right thing to use is debatable. However, I would recommend you look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS2001) and also [this Oracle-base article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/database-triggers-overview) to gain a better understanding of how triggers work and when you might use them.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've tested and saw that it affects all the data with this specific column. As for your advise, an error has occurred saying that table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it.

Comment: It entirely depends on what you're trying to do - sounds like maybe you need to insert the data with the value set in that column already (a before insert for each row) but that may not work for you. I'd advise you to post a new question containing input and expected output data and describe what it is you're trying to do. That way, we can better help you.